# C# How to convert an enum to based Bin/Oct/Dec/Hex string and vice versa

Tags: c#, generics, enums, converters

I was looking for a generic way, representing any type of enum as a bin/oct/dec/hex-based string value.

Convert.To*Type*(Byte,SByte,Int16,UInt16,....) provides support, converting based string to desired type. But Convert.ToString, have just basement support for Type byte (*unsigned*), short(*signed*), int(*signed*), long(*long*). If you don't pay attantion you'll try getting bin-based string from UInt.Max: 
`Convert.ToString(UInt.MaxValue, 2)` But there is no base support for UInt32, so 2 is intepreted as IFormatProvider.
Hex has a ToString Formatprovider, but it gives diffrent output than.  Convert.ToString(,16).

```
Conver.ToString((short)79,16) // 4F
((short)79).ToString("X") // 4f
```

I'll make it quick, no consequent implementation, signed / unsigned problems, casting traps. While working with enum, you dont have an enum generic support. virieté of possible enumbase types and so on.

All what I would like, is representing any enum as based string and cast based string back to desired enum.

Answer (score 0):

I'have put a little effort and created 2 Converters for that, Code implementation are available on following gist:

BasedEnumConverter and Helper: https://gist.github.com/chubbson/816b24a59e5f7e90385e
BasedValueConverter https://gist.github.com/chubbson/375b535243c166d28119

```
void Main()
{

    var os = Tshort.Convesionfailed.ToStringOct().Dump();         //000120
    BasedEnumConverter<Tshort>.ParseEnumFromOct(os).Dump();       //Conversionfailed

    var stsbbin = Tsbyte.BAD.ToStringBin().Dump();                //10000000
    BasedEnumConverter<Tsbyte>.ParseEnumFromBin(stsbbin).Dump();  //BAD

    var sinthex = Tint.OK.ToStringHex().Dump();                   //00000080
    BasedEnumConverter<Tint>.ParseEnumFromHex(sinthex).Dump();    //OK

}

enum Tenum : byte { A = 0, B = 1, OK = 128, BAD = 255, Convesionfailed = 80 }
enum Tbyte : byte { A = 0, B = 1, OK = 128, BAD = 255, Convesionfailed = 80 }
enum Tsbyte : sbyte { A = 0, B = 1, OK = 127, OK2 = 126, BAD = -128, BAD2 = -127, Convesionfailed = 80 }
enum Tshort : short { A = 0, B = 1, OK = 128, BAD = 255, Convesionfailed = 80 }
enum Tushort : ushort { A = 0, B = 1, OK = 128, BAD = 255, Convesionfailed = 80 }
enum Tint : int { A = 0, B = 1, OK = 128, BAD = 255, Convesionfailed = 80 }
enum Tuint: uint { A = 0, B = 1, OK = 128, BAD = 255, Convesionfailed = 80 }
enum Tlong : long { A = 0, B = 1, OK = 128, BAD = 255, Convesionfailed = 80 }
enum Tulong : ulong { A = 0, B = 1, OK = 128, BAD = 255, Convesionfailed = 80, Min = ulong.MinValue, Max = ulong.MaxValue}
```

Please Review the code, give me a hint about performance/oop, what is conceptually wrong or could be done better. My first (or second approach was trying to calc the values by self with some shift and stringappending, but i discarted this cuz of 8 enum base types)